# java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I am trying to return an ArrayList of database search results from a servlet to be displayed on a jsp page.

Setting the arraylist as an attibute of request in the servlet and forwarding the request to the jsp page. when I try to retrieve it on the jsp page it it gives the following error:

"java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList"

The servlet code:

```
List<Car> ResultList=SearchPartsDAO.displaySearchResults(car);
        if(ResultList.size()>=1){
            request.setAttribute("ResultList", ResultList);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("SearchResults.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else
            response.sendRedirect("NotFound.jsp");
```

The JSP:

```
<body>
<% 
ArrayList<Car> resultList = new ArrayList<Car>();
resultList=(ArrayList<Car>)request.getAttribute("ResultList");
%>
<%System.out.println(resultList.get(0).getCarMake());%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displaySearchResults() method is returning a Vector, which is a type of List, but is different from an ArrayList.

In your JSP you should declare resultList as List instead of ArrayList - then it doesn't matter which List implementation the DAO uses. Using the most generic type possible (i.e. List instead of Vector or ArrayList) for variable declarations, return types and parameters is a good practice to follow in general.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't shown your `displaySearchResults` method, but it sounds like that returns a `Vector` rather than an `ArrayList`. But fundamentally, you shouldn't care which implementation it returns - if you just cast to `List<Car>` instead, you should be fine:

```
<body>
<% 
List<Car> resultList = (List<Car>) request.getAttribute("ResultList");
%>
<%System.out.println(resultList.get(0).getCarMake());%>
```

Note how I've removed the initial assignment of an empty `ArrayList` - that's pointless if you're *immediately* going to assign a new value to the variable anyway.

It's cleaner to work in terms of the collection interfaces than the concrete classes - and you're already doing that in your first snippet of code. *That* only requires that the return value implements `List<Car>`, so you should only have the same requirement when you deal with the same value later.

It's also worth understanding that your cast to `List<Car>` is somewhat unsafe, in that it's only *really* casting to `List`, due to the lack of reified generics. You could still get a `ClassCastException` later when you access the individual elements, if they turn out to be some non-`Car` references. Unfortunately there's not a lot you can do about that.

Comment: @SteveK: That doesn't give us any information about what it's returning - which is apparently a `Vector` reference, given the exception you're getting.